# Why must rospy.init_node be after rospy.Publisher?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Consider the following simple program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import std_msgs

if __name__ == "__main__":
        pub = rospy.Publisher('/topic', std_msgs.msg.Int32, queue_size=1)
        rospy.init_node('test_py')
        pub.publish(0)
```

When I run `rostopic echo /topic` and run the node, it outputs `0` as expected.

However, when I swap the position of `init_node` and `Publisher` as so

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import std_msgs

if __name__ == "__main__":
        rospy.init_node('test_py')
        pub = rospy.Publisher('/topic', std_msgs.msg.Int32, queue_size=1)
        pub.publish(0)
```

It is no longer able to publish.

Why is that the case?  Given it would seem more natural (and in line with roscpp) to initialize the node via `init_node` before setting up publishers and subscribers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368644/why-must-rospy.init_node-be-after-rospy.publisher?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-30**:
There is a good chance this is the same as in #q368646.

Publishing a single message *milliseconds* after having created the `Publisher` most likely doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per @gvdhoorn's comment, adding a delay between between `Publisher` and `publish` makes it work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import std_msgs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('test_py')
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/topic', std_msgs.msg.Int32, queue_size=1)
    rospy.sleep(2)
    pub.publish(0)
```

Or better yet, check that a connection is established first

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import std_msgs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('test_py')
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/topic', std_msgs.msg.Int32, queue_size=1)
    while pub.get_num_connections() == 0:
        print("no connections")
        rospy.sleep(0.2)
    print("num connections = " + str(pub.get_num_connections()))
    pub.publish(0)
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1